# How to add reference windows Phone 8 data.entity?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When i try adding entity dll , get this error " Type  universe cannot resolve assembly: system.componentModel.DataAnnotations"

Comment: then try to add reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`

Comment: When you try adding  system.componentModel.DataAnnotations , give again same error getting.